# How to save multiple origin and destination points/markers from google maps on firestore and list them

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I am new to firestore and typescript/angular and as part of my learning i am playing around with googles Maps, Places and Directions API. I was attempting to have a unique user create multiple origin and destination markers which would be saved in firestore then displayed in a list for verification and editing but I am honestly not sure where or how to start. I know I would have to create an array in firestore document for each user detailing the multiple origin and destination markers but how to maneuver around it with typescript is whats got me. Could anyone help me with links or tutorials that can give me an understanding of what I need to do to achieve this?

This is sample code of my current implementation where a user can make an initial origin and destination marker selection.

```
            export class HomePage implements OnInit {
              @ViewChild('search') searchElementRef: ElementRef;
              public searchControl: FormControl;
              public formatted_address: string;
              public options = {
                suppressMarkers: true,
              };
              public waypoints: any = []
              public show = true;
              zoom: number = 8;
              starsCount: number;
              public lat: number = 0.31628;
              public lng: number = 32.58219;
              public address: Object;
              searchItem = '';
              autocompleteItems = [];
              map: any;
              showpickup = '';
              markers = [];
              street: any;
              building: any;
              public origin: any
              public destination: any
              pickup: boolean;
              loader: any;
              block: any;
              color = ['black', 'black', 'black'];
              item: { color: string; size: number; margin: number; hw: number; icolor: string; ml: number; marginpic: number; flag: boolean; name: string }[];
              dir: { origin: { lat: number; lng: number; }; destination: { lat: number; lng: number; }; };
              marker: boolean;
              locatedCountry: string;
              tripDistance: number;

              public markerOptions = {
                origin: {
                  animation: '\'DROP\'',
                  label: 'origin',

                },
                destination: {
                  animation: '\'DROP\'',
                  label: 'destination',

                },
              }
              renderOptions = {
                suppressMarkers: true,
              }

              public screenOptions;

              constructor(
                private __zone: NgZone,
                public geolocation: Geolocation,
                private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
                public serviceProvider: IoncabServicesService,
                public toastCtrl: ToastController,
                public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
                public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public modalCtrl: ModalController,
                public route: Router) {
                if (this.serviceProvider.destination === '') {
                  this.pickup = true;
                  this.marker = true;
                }
                this.getCurrentLoaction();
                this.show = true;
                this.item = [{
                  color: '#f4f4f4',
                  size: 1.2,
                  margin: 0,
                  hw: 40,
                  icolor: 'black',
                  ml: 35,
                  marginpic: 5,
                  flag: false,
                  name: 'black'
                }, {
                  color: '#f4f4f4',
                  size: 1.2,
                  margin: 0,
                  hw: 40,
                  icolor: 'black',
                  ml: 35,
                  marginpic: 5,
                  flag: false,
                  name: 'black'

                }, {
                  color: '#f4f4f4',
                  size: 1.2
                  , margin: 0,
                  hw: 40,
                  icolor: 'black',
                  ml: 35,
                  marginpic: 5,
                  flag: false,
                  name: 'black'
                }];

              }

              reset() {
                this.__zone.run(() => {
                  this.marker = true;
                  this.destination = null;
                  this.serviceProvider.destinationlatitude = null;
                  this.serviceProvider.destinationlongititude = null;
                  this.serviceProvider.pickupLocation = 'pickup';
                  this.pickup = true;
                  this.serviceProvider.showdestination = null;
                  this.origin = null;
                  this.lat = null;
                  this.lng = null;
                  this.getCurrentLoaction();
                })

              }


              async getCurrentLoaction() {
                const loader = await this.serviceProvider.loading('Getting your location..');
                loader.present()
                this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                  console.log(resp)
                  const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
                  const mapOptions = {
                    center: latLng,
                    zoom: 8,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  }
                  this.lat = resp.coords.latitude
                  this.lng = resp.coords.longitude
                  this.serviceProvider.directionlat = this.lat
                  this.serviceProvider.directionlng = this.lng
                  // this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapOptions);
                  this.getGeoLocation(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
                  this.serviceProvider.originlatitude = this.lat;
                  this.serviceProvider.originlongititude = this.lng
                  this.origin = { lat: this.serviceProvider.originlatitude, lng: this.serviceProvider.originlongititude };

                  loader.dismiss();

                }).catch((error) => {
                  console.log('Error getting location', error);
                }).finally(() => {
                })
              }

              async getGeoLocation(lat: number, lng: number) {
                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                  const geocoder = await new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  const latlng = await new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                  const request = { latLng: latlng };

                  await geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      const result = results[0];
                      const rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
                      if (result !== null) {
                        if (rsltAdrComponent[0] !== null) {
                          this.block = rsltAdrComponent[0].long_name;
                          this.street = rsltAdrComponent[2].short_name;
                          this.building = rsltAdrComponent[1].short_name;
                        }
                        // Find out country of geolocation
                        console.log(rsltAdrComponent);
                        for (let i = 0; i < rsltAdrComponent.length; i++) {
                          if (rsltAdrComponent[i].types && rsltAdrComponent[i].types.includes('country')) {
                            this.locatedCountry = rsltAdrComponent[i].short_name;
                          }
                        }

                        if (this.serviceProvider.flag === true && this.serviceProvider.pickup !== 'Uganda') {
                          this.serviceProvider.showpickup = this.block + ' ' + this.street + ' ' + this.building;
                        } else if (this.serviceProvider.pickup !== 'Uganda') {
                          this.serviceProvider.showdestination = this.street + this.building;
                        }
                      } else {
                        alert('No address available!');
                      }
                    }
                  });
                }
              }


              changeStyle(j) {
                for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  this.item[i].ml = 0;
                  this.item[i].color = '#f4f4f4';
                  this.item[i].size = 1.2;
                  this.item[i].margin = 0;
                  this.item[i].marginpic = 5;
                  this.item[i].icolor = 'black';
                  this.item[i].hw = 45;
                  this.color[i] = 'black';
                  this.item[i].flag = false;
                  this.item[i].name = 'black';
                }
                this.item[j].flag = true;
                this.color[j] = 'orange';
                this.item[j].hw = 50;
                this.item[j].margin = 5;
                this.item[j].color = 'orange';
                this.item[j].size = 2;
                this.item[j].ml = 0;
                this.item[j].marginpic = 0;
                this.item[j].icolor = 'white';
                this.item[j].name = 'orange'

              }


              clickedMarker(label: string, index: number) {
                console.log(`clicked the marker: ${label || index}`)
              }
              async markerDragEnd(m: marker, $event: MouseEvent) {
                console.log('dragEnd', m, $event);
                if ($event.coords && $event.coords.lat && $event.coords.lng) {
                  const geocoder = await new google.maps.Geocoder();
                  const latlng = await new google.maps.LatLng($event.coords.lat, $event.coords.lng);
                  const request = { latLng: latlng };

                  await geocoder.geocode(request, (results, status) => {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                      const result = results[0];
                      const rsltAdrComponent = result.address_components;
                      if (result !== null) {
                        if (rsltAdrComponent[0] !== null) {
                          this.block = rsltAdrComponent[0].long_name;
                          this.street = rsltAdrComponent[2].short_name;
                          this.building = rsltAdrComponent[1].short_name;
                        }
                        this.__zone.run(() => {
                          if (this.serviceProvider.pickupLocation === 'pickup') {
                            this.serviceProvider.originlatitude = $event.coords.lat;
                            this.serviceProvider.originlongititude = $event.coords.lng;
                            this.origin = { lat: this.serviceProvider.originlatitude, lng: this.serviceProvider.originlongititude };

                            this.serviceProvider.showpickup = this.block + ' ' + this.street + ' ' + this.building;
                          }
                          if (this.serviceProvider.pickupLocation === 'destination') {
                            this.serviceProvider.destinationlatitude = $event.coords.lat; // service value of destination latitude
                            this.serviceProvider.destinationlongititude = $event.coords.lng; // service value of destination longitude
                            this.destination = { lat: this.serviceProvider.destinationlatitude, lng: this.serviceProvider.destinationlongititude }; // local value of destination coords

                            this.serviceProvider.showdestination = this.block + ' ' + this.street + ' ' + this.building;

                          }

                        })

                      } else {
                        alert('No address available!');
                      }

                    }
                  });
                }
              }
              mapClicked($event: MouseEvent) {
                this.markers.push({
                  lat: $event.coords.lat,
                  lng: $event.coords.lng,
                  draggable: true
                });
              }

              ngOnInit() {
              }

              async gotoEdit(name, value, open) {
                this.serviceProvider.pickupLocation = name;
                if (open === 'modal') {
                  const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
                    component: SetlocationComponent,
                    componentProps: { country: this.locatedCountry ? this.locatedCountry : 'UG' }
                  });

                  await modal.present();
                  await modal.onDidDismiss();
                  if (this.serviceProvider.showpickup === '') {
                    this.origin = { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng }
                  } else {
                    if (this.serviceProvider.originlatitude && this.serviceProvider.originlongititude) {
                      this.origin = { lat: this.serviceProvider.originlatitude, lng: this.serviceProvider.originlongititude }
                    } else {
                      this.origin = { lat: this.lat, lng: this.lng }
                    }
                    this.destination = { lat: this.serviceProvider.destinationlatitude, lng: this.serviceProvider.destinationlongititude }
                    if (this.destination && this.destination.lat && this.destination.lng) {
                      this.marker = false;
                    } else {
                      this.marker = true;
                    }

                  }

                }
                this.pickup = value

              }


              public onResponse(event: any) {
                console.log(event);
                this.tripDistance = Math.round(((event.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value) / 1000));
                setTimeout(() => {
                  this.serviceProvider.tripDistance = this.tripDistance;
                }, 5000);
              }
            }


            interface marker {
              lat: number;
              lng: number;
              label?: string;
              draggable: boolean;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post your code whatever you tried!

Comment: The subject of the question is too large and it would take a lot of time for people to help you on. I think it's best to advance as much as you can and post different questions of the different parts where you need help.